# Flutter - Get/Set Android and IOS device name for Bluetooth/Wifi/Hotspot discovery

Tags: android, ios, flutter, device, device-name

I tried to use the device_info_plus package but I could not find any options for getting or setting the Android or Ios device user name so that it appears as `Someone's Iphone` on wifi/bluetooth discovery.
Is not there any method to achieve that?

Comment: Definitely not on iOS. Nay the user can rename their device in settings.

Comment: @Paulw11 Why ? Definitely, my project going garbage :/

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. You can get the device name via [`UIDevice.current.name`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620015-name) but whether other devices will see this in a Bluetooth advertisement depends on whether that device is paired. There is no way to change the actual device name. If you are advertising a peripheral then you can pass `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey` when you advertise via CBPeripheralManager, but again in my experience this often has no effect on what another device sees

Comment: You would need to work out how Flutter accesses these native services on iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks Paul. So is there any method to get my Device's Bluetooth mac address? Which is discoverable when someone makes a Bluetooth device search.

Comment: No, there is no access to the Bluetooth MAC address on iOS; you cannot get your own MAC address and each iOS peripheral device has a unique identifier for each partner (ie device "a" will see identifier "x" and device "b" will see identifier "y" for the same peripheral "c"

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';

DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
print('Running on ${androidInfo.model}');  // e.g. "Moto G (4)"

IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
print('Running on ${iosInfo.utsname.machine}');  // e.g. "iPod7,1"
```

Comment: I mention about Device Name. This code does not work. For example, In IOS the result should return like "Name's iPhone".